# How to add jquery and view helpers to zend framework application?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I need to ad a view helper to my application
The manual says to add the line
`$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");`
But where do I add it to if I'm simply returning the arrays from the controller?

Thanks,
Ofer

Answer (score 0):

`$view` is the view object of the controller

The code should be like this

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');

$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
```

If you need them throughout your application, you can register them in your bootstrap file. Check the ZF manual [zendx.jquery.view](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zendx.jquery.view.html) for more info.